# Automatic offset in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting data from a datafile and the data has behaviour that after a while on the x-axis the y-axis start to monotonically decrease and ultimately go to zero (with some very small fluctuations later on).

Hence, I want to offset the y-axis so that those fluctuations are clearly visible. For that I use something like `set offsets 0,0,0,0.1`. But I have actually written a bash script to generate the plot for me. I just need to provide the datafile name to it. So for each plot I don't want to go into the script and manually set offset value based on the data.

I would like if the offset were determined by `gnuplot` automatically based on the bin-size on the axis, like the offset is 1*bin-size. So my command could look like :

```
set offsets 0,0,0,1*$bin_size
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit:

This is the script I am using.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Requires that the script be in the same directory as the data files
#sed -n '3001,4000p' fish_data_re.dat > fish_data_re_3k_4k.dat : Can be used to extract data from specific range in data file

DATA_FILE_NAME="abc"
DATA_FILE_TYPE="dat"


#Code to generate normalised files
awk 'NR == FNR {if(max < $2) {max = $2}; next} {$2 = $2 / max; printf "%f\t%f\n", $1, $2}' $DATA_FILE_NAME.$DATA_FILE_TYPE $DATA_FILE_NAME.$DATA_FILE_TYPE > $DATA_FILE_NAME\_normed.$DATA_FILE_TYPE

DATA_FILE_NAME="$DATA_FILE_NAME\_normed"
DATA_FILE_TYPE="dat"

OUTPUT_FILE_TYPE="eps"
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME="$DATA_FILE_NAME\_plot.$OUTPUT_FILE_TYPE"

X_LABEL="Time"
Y_LABEL="Real Classical Fisher Information"
TITLE="Real Classical Fisher Information vs Time"

#Set font size for axis tics
X_TICS_SIZE="6"
Y_TICS_SIZE="6"


gnuplot <<- MULTI_LINE_CODE_TAG

set xlabel "$X_LABEL"
set ylabel "$Y_LABEL"

#Following command allows the printing of underscore from name of data file in plot
set key noenhanced

set title "$TITLE" 

set xtics font ", $X_TICS_SIZE"
set ytics font ", $Y_TICS_SIZE"

set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror

#set ytics format "%.22g"
set ytics format "%0.s*10^{%L}"
#set xtics format "%t"



set multiplot

#------The big-plot------

set title "$TITLE" 
set offsets 0,0,0,0.01

#Following plots only data from line 1 to line 100
#plot "<(sed -n '1,100p' $DATA_FILE_NAME.$DATA_FILE_TYPE)" u 1:2 notitle w l lc "red" lw 2 
plot "$DATA_FILE_NAME.$DATA_FILE_TYPE" u 1:2 notitle w l lc "red" lw 2

#------The sub-plot------

unset title
unset offsets

set origin 0.25,0.3
set size 0.45,0.45
set xrange [30:60]
set yrange [-0.01:0.01]
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
#unset label

plot "$DATA_FILE_NAME.$DATA_FILE_TYPE" u 1:2 notitle w l lc "red" lw 2

unset multiplot

set term "$OUTPUT_FILE_TYPE"
set output "$OUTPUT_FILE_NAME"

replot

MULTI_LINE_CODE_TAG

exit
```

As you can see I need to provide the offset manually.

Here is the plot I am getting.

[image]
The y-axis here got offset by <s>-0.002</s> -0.2. I want to automate this thing and want `gnuplot` to always use the the offset as the size of a bin (which I define as the distance between successive tics).

(If this is a trivial question I apologise in advance, I am quite new to gnuplot.)

Comment: it's not fully clear to me what you want. What do you mean with bin-size? If you want to show small fluctuations towards zero maybe logscale might be an option? Please show some example data, example graph and some code.

Comment: @theozh Updated with the required code and graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I still don't understand your exact problem. By the way, your offset it -200e-3 = -0.2 not -0.002.
Is your data always between 0 and 1?
You could set the offsets depending on the graph (check `help offsets`)

```
set offsets 0,0,0, graph 0.2
```

In general, why not using logarithmic scale? With this you will be able to see all small features in your data.

**Code:**

```
### linear scale vs logarithmic scale
reset session 

# Gauss curve by specifing Amplitude A, position x0 and width via FWHM
GaussW(x,x0,A,FWHM) = A * exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*(FWHM/(2*sqrt(2*log(2))))**2))

# create some test data
set xrange[0:100]
set samples 500
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(GaussW($1,5,1,2.5) + GaussW($1,40,7e-3,2) + GaussW($1,47,8e-4,5) + 2e-4) w table
unset table

set multiplot layout 1,2
    set offset 0,0,0, graph 0.2
    set yrange[-0.02:1]
    plot $Data u 1:2 w l title "linear y-scale"

    set logscale y
    set yrange[1e-4:1]
    plot $Data u 1:2 w l title "logarithmic y-scale"
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That does it. Also, accept my thanks for the edit.